# What is the default value of a specific dimension(width,height etc) of a container

Tags: css

What will be the default value of a dimension(in terms of width, height, size etc) of a container(say ul element or footer element) if the container is not given any specific value for any of these (width, height, size etc) in it css styling.

And also what size will be assumed by say, an image whose width is 100% and nested inside such a dimensionless container.

I am asking because if an image of 100% width is nested inside a container with a specified width, the image can only occupy 100% of that specified width of it container. What if the container has no defined value for any dimension?

Comment: can you show some code? what have you tried ?

Comment: if container is 100% and does not have another container. the width will be the whole window. and the image inside it having 100% width will also stretch with it.

Comment: default value of an HTML element is AUTO.

Answer (score 0):

When no width specified the default value of an element is AUTO. Browser calculates the width. it is for further reference please visit --> [W3 Schools HTML Element WIDTH](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp)

For more detail you can also visit. [w3.org Width Property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property)